How to dual booting ARM Windows on an Apple Silicon Mac?
I was looking online, and it appears that Microsoft has released an ARM64 version of Windows, and I am wondering if it is possible to dual boot my MacBook Pro M3 into it.
I do know that you can dual boot different versions of macOS, but I was not able to find out online if this is possible with Windows as of now.
Has this been done before? How would you go about it? What are the limitations?

That image is meant for a PC based on a Snapdragon CPU, which is what Microsoft is officially supporting.  It will not boot on a Mac.
From the Learn More link:

For devices with a Snapdragon X Series processor, booting from an ISO
to install Windows is supported without additional drivers from device
manufacturers.

